# Поместить числа из файла в переменную

Tags: c++

Всем привет
у меня есть файл,в нем такие вот строки
$-чтобы вставить \n при распечатке
Мне нужно взять из каждой строки подчеркнутые значения и поместить их в переменные.Перемножить их и прибавить это значение к уже имеющейся сумме.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Похоже вам надо читать файл построчно и выбирать числа после первого и шестого двоеточия

Comment: именно,я уже и прописал функцию,которая читает строки
но вот как взять числа после первого и шестого двоеточия я не придумал...

Comment: Ищите двоеточие `for (int i = 0; str[i]; i++) if (str[i] == ':') { n2++; ...`, если оно первое или шестое `if (n2 == 1 || n2 == 6) { int *p = &v1; if (n2 == 6) p = &v2; sscanf(str + i + 1, "%i", p);` читаете число

Comment: ```void ReturnSum(string item) {
    string InputReysDetails = { "InputReysDetails.txt" };
    ifstream finSumm;
    finSumm.open(InputReysDetails);
    if (!finSumm.is_open()) {
        cout << "Ошибка открытия файла для чтения" << endl;
    }
    else {
        while (getline(finSumm,item)) {
        }
    }}```
Не знаю зачем она вам,обычный getline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Первая функция находит все ":" в строке.

Вторая - все числа после них.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

std::vector<unsigned int> find_colons(std::string string){
    int str_size = string.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < str_size; i++) 
    if (string[i] == ':') r.push_back(i);
    return r;
}

std::vector<int> find_diggits(std::string string, std::vector<unsigned int> colons_index_array){
    std::vector<int> r;
    unsigned int col_size = colons_index_array.size();
    std::string temp;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < col_size; i++){
        for (unsigned int j = colons_index_array[i]+1; j < string.size(); j++)
            if (isdigit(string[j])) temp.push_back(string[j]);
            else break;
        r.push_back(atoi(temp.c_str()));
        temp.clear();
    }
    return r;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    std::string string = "dsaf:15433 fadfa d:545f afas:12 f";
    std::vector<int> r = find_diggits(string, find_colons(string));
    int rsize = r.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < rsize; i++) std::cout << r[i] << " "; // 15433 545 12
    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Имейте в виду, что эти функции нельзя использовать как корректное представление данных из файла, поскольку разделителем часов и минут в вашем файле также является двоеточие.

В принципе же в выходном массиве у вас будут часы и минуты в двух разных соседних элементах.

Comment: Хотя я бы на вашем месте написал бы небольшой парсер строки в словарь для вашего файла. Аля `$*:*$*:*$` == `{"*":"*", "*":"*"}`. Если структурно подходить к решению любой задачи, выходит просто, читаемо и красиво.

Comment: Я извиняюсь,это Пайтон?
Спасибо конечно,но я в нем полный 0

Comment: Простите, что-то у меня голову перекосило, когда ответ писал х)
Сейчас перепишу на плюсы

Comment: @ОсяСаакян Реализовал на cpp, за питона своего извиняюсь, хотя в принципе вы бы могли рассмотреть его как псевдокод для решения вашей задачи. Вы же изучите этот пример и возьмете на заметку на будущее, чтобы в перспективе самому решить подобную задачу, а не просто скопируете и забудете, так?)